How to write a MD5 SQL Code in Oracle similar to Informatica Expression Logic for Validation
My requirement is to write a sql code to replicate the MD5 Logic used in informatica expression transformation for Validation Purpose . The MD5 used in Informatica is MD5(TRIM(AGRMNT_NO)||TRIM(SRC_CD)) . I tried Writing the Logic in sql as shown below but it keeps throwing error .
SQL_CODE :
SELECT
    STANDARD_HASH(AGRMNT_NO || SRC_CD)
FROM
    EODS_STG.STG1_EODS_BACC_POLICY
WHERE
    STG1_EODS_BACC_POLICY.BACC_PR_TYPEX IN ('OR','AN')


"I tried Writing the Logic in sql as shown below but it keeps throwing error ." is not a constructive statement. Please [edit] the question and include the full text of the error.

Your code works without errors fiddle (but it is trivially to get a hash collision).

The code should also use TRIM function to be equivalent SELECT STANDARD_HASH(TRIM(AGRMNT_NO) || TRIM(SRC_CD)) - but that doesn't change the already pointed out fact that it does not throw any error. Please review the question.
